# How can I improve my UML modellisation of the following code in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, uml

I am modelling a basic code in c++ using UML.
I have a first draft.
I would like to have a feedback about how I could improve it or if I missed something or if there is something wrong with the graph.

The UML diagram:
[image: structural diagram]

And the code:

```cpp
#include <ctime>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <numeric>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


// CLASS: declaration -------------------------------------
// # Animal ...............................................
class Animal{
    private:
        std::string name;
        double height;
        double weight;

        // member of a class as static { bit.ly/2EXnDTW }
        static int numOfAnimals;
    public:
        static int GetNumOfAnimals(){return numOfAnimals;}

        void SetName(std::string name){this->name = name;} //<mutator/SETTER
        std::string GetName(){return name;} //<accessor/GETTER

        void SetHeight(double height){this->height = height;}
        double GetHeight(){return height;}

        void SetWeight(double weight){this->weight = weight;}
        double GetWeight(){return weight;}

        //note: possible not to provide a name here with your prototypes
        //ex: void SetAll(std::string, double, double);
        void SetAll(std::string name, double height, double weight);

        Animal(std::string name, double height, double weight); //<constructor
        Animal(); //<overload constructor when no attributes are passed
        ~Animal(); //<deconstructor

        void ToString();
};

int Animal::numOfAnimals = 0;

void Animal::SetAll(std::string name, double height, double weight){
    this->name = name;
    this->height = height;
    this->weight = weight;
}
//constructor
Animal::Animal(std::string name, double height, double weight){
    this->name = name;
    this->height = height;
    this->weight = weight;
    Animal::numOfAnimals++;
}
//overload constructor when no attributes are passed
Animal::Animal(){
    this->name = "";
    this->height = 0;
    this->weight = 0;
    Animal::numOfAnimals++;
}
//destructor
Animal::~Animal(){ std::cout << "Animal " << this -> name << " destroyed\n";}

void Animal::ToString(){
    std::cout << this -> name << " is "
              << this -> height << " cms tall and "
              << this -> weight << " kgs in weight\n";
}

// # Dog ..................................................
class Dog: public Animal{
    private:
        std::string sound = "woof";
    public:
        void MakeSound(){ printf("The dog %s says %s\n", this->GetName().c_str(), this->sound.c_str());}
        Dog(std::string name, double height, double weight, std::string sound);
        Dog(): Animal(){};
        void ToString();
};

Dog::Dog(std::string name, double height, double weight, std::string sound) :
Animal(name, height, weight){
    this->sound = sound;
}

void Dog::ToString(){
    //printf("%s is %d cms tall and %d kgs in weight and says %s\n",
    //        this->GetName().c_str(), this->GetHeight(), this->GetWeight(), this->sound.c_str());
    // note: do not work well with this->GetHeight() and this->GetWeight()
    std::cout << this -> GetName()   << " is "
              << this -> GetHeight() << " cms tall and "
              << this -> GetWeight() << " kgs in weight and says "
              << this -> sound       << "\n";
}

// END CLASS ----------------------------------------------

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    //create 1st animal - fred
    Animal fred;
    //test overloaded constructor
    fred.ToString();
    //add attributes value of 1st animal - Fred
    fred.SetHeight(33);
    fred.SetWeight(10);
    fred.SetName("Fred");
    fred.ToString();
    //create 2nd animal using constructor - tom
    Animal tom("Tom", 36, 15);
    tom.ToString();
    //create 1st dog - spot
    Dog spot("Spot", 38, 16, "woofWoof");
    //print 2nd dog info
    spot.ToString();
    spot.MakeSound();
    //print number of animal
    std::cout << "Number of Animals : " << Animal::GetNumOfAnimals() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The expected and current output of the code:

- is 0 cms tall and 0 kgs in weight
- Fred is 33 cms tall and 10 kgs in weight
- Tom is 36 cms tall and 15 kgs in weight
- Spot is 38 cms tall and 16 kgs in weight and says woofWoof
- The dog Spot says woofWoof
- Number of Animals : 3
- Animal Spot destroyed
- Animal Tom destroyed
- Animal Fred destroyed

Comment: I put some remarks in an answer, hoping useful for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best place is not here but on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ (for the code only)

However few remarks :

- the code and the UML modelisation are consistent, and the code can be compiled without warning, that is great
- why `A01 : Animal` rather than `fred : Animal`, `A02 : Animal` rather than `tom : Animal` and `D01 : Dog` rather than `spot : Dog` ?
- The notation in the class diagram for the parameters of the operations does not follow the UML standard, for instance `SetName(string name) : void` must be `SetName(in name : string) : void` or `SetName(name : string) : void` if the direction is hidden.
- I encourage you to use *const* operation the more you can, for instance for the *getters* (*GetName*, *GetHeight* ...)
- in the constructor without argument you do not need to do `this->name = "";`, fortunately `std::string` as a constructor making an empty string
- `Animal::ToString()` and `Dog::ToString()` dodoes not make a string, iteyt write on stdout, their names are misleading
- you declare the destructors but you do not define them
- because *Animal* is a base class put its *destructor* *virtual*. This is needed in case you delete an instance from a pointer of *Animal* being in fact an instance of a sub class. You missed to decrement *numOfAnimals* in it.
- It is better to have *ToString* *virtual* to call the version depending on the real type of the instance rather than the type known at compile time. Add `{ Animal * a = &spot; a->ToString(); }` in *main* and look at the result.
- Why are you using *printf* in `MakeSound()` ?
- you allow to instantiate *Animal*, it is an acceptable choice, an other is too make that class abstract to only allow to instantiate sub classes associated to effective animals
- Personally I only use an uppercase character to start the name of an operation (and attribute) when it is *static*, that allows to distinguish them.

P.S. considering your picture on S.O. I am surprised that there is no monkey class ;-)

Comment: Hm. `numOfAnimals` as property of `Animal` sounds more than strange.

Comment: @ThomasKilian Why ? it is the number of instances of animals ... supposing to decrement its value in the destructor rather than only increment it in the constructors ;-) (I edited my answer, I did not see that before, I just checked both constructors increment it)

Comment: No sense. One instance is one animal. You can have a count in an animal collection. But that's something totally different.

Comment: @ThomasKilian I do not understand, if I have 3 dogs and 2 cats I have 5 animals, that has sense, independently of the fact it may have a count in each specie in the corresponding classes

Comment: @ThomasKilian and that independently there is or not a collection of all the ANimals and same for each sub classes. One know we are like 7,534 giga humans on the earth, where is the collection ?

Comment: @ThomasKilian What about the person in the spacial station or on the moon when their was/will be, are they not human :-) More seriously is there is a collection memorizing the Animals that one can give how much Animals there are. The reason _numOfAnimals_ is useful is precisely because there is *no* collection. In the OP code there are up to 3 Animals, and no collection memorizing them.

Comment: Bruno, I don't get it. This construct is simply nonsense. I'm just too old to go into futile discussions.